# Loopback - how to determine the name of the method based on the endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, loopbackjs, loopback

Loopback 3

My Customer method extends the User method. In addition, I have an endpoint:

```
GET / Customers / {id} / orders
```

How to check the method name of the endpoint **GET /Customers/{id}/orders**?

I need it for the property name in ACL generator

Answer (score 0):

```
GET / Customers/id/orders
```

in router for /Customers

```
router.get('/:id/orders',function(req,res,next){
   code whatever you wish
});
```

you can extract value of id as `req.params.id`